# Criptografar senha no app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ola, pessoal estou com a seguinte situação fiz uma aplicação e algumas conexões fiz via wizard do visual C# só que o mesmo criou um arquivo chamando app.config com as informações de conexão como abaixo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="_4Award.Properties.Settings.controleBDConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\controleBD.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=base1"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="_4Award.Properties.Settings.controleBDConnectionString1"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\controleBD.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=base1"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="_4Award.Properties.Settings.controleBDConnectionString2"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\controleBD.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=base1"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="_4Award.Properties.Settings.controleBDConnectionString3"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\controleBD.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=base1"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de criptografar a senha pra ficar dessa forma como vi em uma outra aplicação

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="CONNECTION_SQLSERVER" connectionString="Data Source=PARKING-PC\PONTOSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ACESSOBD;User Id=DEFAULT_ACESSO;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=60;Password=" />
    <add name="PASSWORD_CONNECTION_SQLSERVER" connectionString="CGCCTKQ" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Depende de como está usando a connection string. Você tem o código que faz uso dela?

Comment: vou dar uma olhada no projeto e depois posto, como eu disse fiz essa conexão via Wizard do Visual Studio C# para agilizar a criação da aplicação, mas acabei encontando essa falha de segurança para a o programa que criei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, tem uma forma. Eu já precisei de fazer isso, mas fiz da forma mais simples possível. Eu monto toda essa estrutura de conexão via código.

Por exemplo, no meu arquivo de app.config ou web.config, eu não tenho a connectionStrings. Para montar eu uso appsetting, dessa forma:

```
**<appSettings>
    <add key="Server" value="servidor"/> <!--Servidor-->
    <add key="Base" value="Base"/> <!--Nome da base-->
    <add key="User" value="Usuario"/>    <!--User-->
    <add key="password" value="pp$*#KCMJIIR*@_pLO(#(*"/>  <!--Senha criptografada-->

</appSettings>**
```

"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id{2};Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=60;Password={3}"

E via código, eu descriptografo a senha, crio a estrutura connectionStrings e em tempo de execução envio para o metodo de acesso a dados, ou entity e etc. Se é a melhor forma, não sei, fiz o que eu precisava no meu projeto.

Comment: no meu caso esse arquivo app.config apareceu com essas informações da minha conncetion string devido eu ter criado um data set usando o wizard do visual studio e eu queria saber se existe alguma forma pelo wizard de criptografar pelo menos a senha

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas respostas, e @Paulo César a sua resposta foi uma boa abordagem, e fiz semelhante a sua forma, leio o arquivo via codigo e altero a linha especifica da senha, criptografando ela.